# AllocConsole() doesnt show up

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'm trying to inject a dll into a testprogam and use AllocConsole() for debugging.

```
AllocConsole();
```

However， the console wont show up and I realized that the program I was trying to inject is running under SYSTEM and I was using an administrator account so the console wont show up on my desktop. Only the conhost process was created.

So... How to make a console from AllocConsole() show up on every accounts desktop?

Comment: ***How to make a console from AllocConsole() show up on every accounts desktop?*** Depending on what you are doing, your OS may prevent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is running as `SYSTEM` so likely it's a service running in the services session (session 0). It's not possible to allocate a console and show it in another session (e.g. the console session). It's not possible for a process to have a window (or console) that is visible in all sessions or even on multiple desktops.

If you don't know what Session Isolation is best start reading here: [Application Compatibility - Session 0 Isolation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361)

If you want to output simple debugging, an easy method is using [OutputDebugString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringw) (and use a tool like [DbgView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to read the output) or writing to the eventlog. For more detailed output you could setup a named pipe or some other inter processs communication.